# Paused/restarted animation does not call delegate methods

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I have a CAKeyframeAnimation that calls animationDidStart: and animationDidStop:finished:, as expected, when the animation is allowed to run its course.

When I pause the animation during interruptions (calls, home btn pressed, etc) animationDidStop:finished: fires with a flag of NO, as expected.

However, after restarting the paused animation, animationDidStart: and animationDidStop:finished: are never fired again. The animation does visually continue and complete, but I don't receive the event. I need to know when the animation stops so I can restart my game loop.

I followed [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1673.html) for the pause/restart of the animation.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong. Thanks!

```
- (void)takeFlight
{   
    CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    pathAnimation.duration = FLY_ANIM_TIME;
    pathAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    pathAnimation.delegate = self;

    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/3);
    CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, xPos, yPos);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, -100.0, -50.0, 200.0, 100.0);
    pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
    CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

    [shipView.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"flyin"];
    shipView.center = endPoint; 
}

-(void)pauseFlight
{
    CALayer *layer = (CALayer *)shipView.layer;
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    layer.speed = 0.0;
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}

-(void)resumeFlight
{   
    CALayer *layer = (CALayer *)shipView.layer;
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
    layer.speed = 1.0;
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    layer.beginTime = 0.0;
    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}

- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)animation
{
    NSLog(@"anim did start");
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)flag
{   
    NSLog(@"anim did stop, flag is: %d", flag);

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty surprised that you get the animationDidStop:finished: callback when you pause the animation. Are you sure this is what's happening? (Perhaps look at the stack trace in this call?) The docs say you should get that when the animation is removed (which it isn't) or passes its "active duration" (which I wouldn't expect to happen when you set the speed to 0).

Comment: I was surprised about that too, but it is definitely calling it and the animation appears to stop. Visually, it appears to restart and complete when I un-pause it. I don't get a stack trace... I guess because there is no exception? (Not sure I understand the whole stack trace thing, I'm still new to this.) - Victoria

Comment: I added breakpoints and see the animationDidStop:finished: in the debugger (is this the "back trace"?). Just like the console log, it shows the method being called when the animation is paused, but not when it finishes it second leg (after unpause). Is there anything I can add that would be helpful? I'm lost....

Comment: This is definitely not working as documented, so I have submitted a tech support request to Apple. I will update here when I know more.